# Unable to deploy my program on the internet

Tags: javascript, user-interface, processing

I have created a TicTacToe program in JavaScript using the Processing Library for GUI. Now I want to put it on a website. [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) allows us to do this but despite many tries I cant seem to get it working.

I am uploading my files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B28ukDt23ETRZmdUZlpaZDBiRTg). It contains my Processing sketch, my html file and processing.js file. Also contains a text file which I use in my algorithm.

First I tried using the sketch directly by using this syntax:

```
<script src="processing.js"></script> 
<canvas data-processing-sources="anything.pde"></canvas>
```

but when I did that my browser showed just a blank page. Next I tried to put all my code in the html file itself as mentioned on the processing.js website. When I do that the game loads on the page, I can make a move but the computer does not make a move as it is supposed to. I have tested the program extensively and it does run in Processing IDE.

UPDATE:
So I checked the JavaScript console and found that the possibilities.txt file which I use in my program is not getting loaded. Here is what the console says:

```
processing.js:11 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
ajax @ processing.js:11
p.loadStrings @ processing.js:13904
fillStore @ VM56:340
caller @ VM56:164
mouseClicked @ VM56:121
(anonymous) @ processing.js:7613
processing.js:16 Failed to load file:///D:/possibilities.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
ajax @ processing.js:16
p.loadStrings @ processing.js:13904
fillStore @ VM56:340
caller @ VM56:164
mouseClicked @ VM56:121
(anonymous) @ processing.js:7613
processing.js:16 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///D:/possibilities.txt'.
    at ajax (http://localhost:8081/processing.js:16:9)
    at Processing.Processing.p.loadStrings (http://localhost:8081/processing.js:13904:25)
    at Processing.Processing.fillStore (eval at attach (http://localhost:8081/processing.js:718:22), <anonymous>:340:16)
    at Processing.Processing.caller (eval at attach (http://localhost:8081/processing.js:718:22), <anonymous>:164:3)
    at Processing.Processing.mouseClicked (eval at attach (http://localhost:8081/processing.js:718:22), <anonymous>:121:6)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8081/processing.js:7613:9)
ajax @ processing.js:16
p.loadStrings @ processing.js:13904
fillStore @ VM56:340
caller @ VM56:164
mouseClicked @ VM56:121
(anonymous) @ processing.js:7613
```

Also hosted the file on a localhost server and tried.. Still no luck. Console displayed this error:

```
processing.js:11 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
ajax @ processing.js:11
p.loadStrings @ processing.js:13904
fillStore @ VM25:340
caller @ VM25:164
mouseClicked @ VM25:121
(anonymous) @ processing.js:7613
processing.js:16 Failed to load http://localhost:8081/possibilities.txt: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.
ajax @ processing.js:16
p.loadStrings @ processing.js:13904
fillStore @ VM25:340
caller @ VM25:164
mouseClicked @ VM25:121
(anonymous) @ processing.js:7613
processing.js:16 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:8081/possibilities.txt'.
    at ajax (file:///D:/web/processing.js:16:9)
    at Processing.Processing.p.loadStrings (file:///D:/web/processing.js:13904:25)
    at Processing.Processing.fillStore (eval at attach (file:///D:/web/processing.js:718:22), <anonymous>:340:16)
    at Processing.Processing.caller (eval at attach (file:///D:/web/processing.js:718:22), <anonymous>:164:3)
    at Processing.Processing.mouseClicked (eval at attach (file:///D:/web/processing.js:718:22), <anonymous>:121:6)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.<anonymous> (file:///D:/web/processing.js:7613:9)
ajax @ processing.js:16
p.loadStrings @ processing.js:13904
fillStore @ VM25:340
caller @ VM25:164
mouseClicked @ VM25:121
(anonymous) @ processing.js:7613
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be looking at [the JavaScript console](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) to see any errors that your code is throwing.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on deploying Processing using Processing.js, available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js).

You haven't posted a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please try to do so in the future) so I can't tell exactly what's going on, but my guess is that you're using a Java-only feature in your code, which causes JavaScript to throw an error. If that's the case, then you'll need to get rid of that Java code.